# Is it possible to use sqlite instead of sqflite in flutter? if yes, then how?

Tags: dart, flutter

or else let me know how to create a simple database in flutter using sqflite in flutter. That is having just a single and textfield and that value need to be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) for it.